# Why when I click on the update button error TypeError: r is undefined happen?

Tags: popup, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The error in firefox browser as follows: TypeError: r is undefined

This is the chrome browser:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

I also did a video for a better understanding.

The error occurs when I changed the values ​​in a field

[**jsfiddle code**](http://jsfiddle.net/mSRUe/19/embedded/result/)

[**youtube video**](http://youtu.be/Ae5u7mFw79A)

**button code update**

```js
      save: function (e) {
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({

                url: '/api/apdevice',
                type: e.model.id == null ? 'POST' : 'PUT',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(e.model),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('yes');
                    that.refresh();
                },

                error: function (data) {
                    alert('no');
                    that.cancelRow();
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: I can't watch your video unfortunately, but I am getting following error in Chrome while loading you Fiddle : Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. [VM] lastError (856):29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Comment: Now you can see Video

Comment: Your JSFiddle does not produce an error for me in chrome nor firefox. Does it for you?

Comment: I've tested several other computers and I get the error when you click on the button edit
The amount of change opens the popup and then click on the update button.
It can also test http://jsfiddle.net/mSRUe/19/embedded/result/

Comment: Oh, looks like I actually needed to change field data to see the error.

Comment: Yes, you should change the value popup fields and then click on the update button to see the error.**You can also see video**

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is because your datasource's update method is being called. It has not been set which gives you the `TypeError`.

You can do one of two things.

1. Set the update method of your datasource to contain the logic contained in your save function. You'll need to set update as a function in order to be able to control the method dynamically (POST/PUT). You should remove the ajax code from the save event at this point.
2. Set the update method to a dummy function and handle it as part of the save event instead.

Here's an example of approach #2.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  ..
  update: function(e) { return true; }
  ..
});
```

Keep the save event function as is.

Note that I'm getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` error. I believe this is originating from the `LastClientsCount` property.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mSRUe/23/

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
Can you put an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: I get this error in firefox browser:SyntaxError: missing ; before 
d.0=value and in error chrome browser: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number,I've also added code "LastClientsCount" also still gives error.http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/mSRUe/24/

Comment: Yeah, like I said there is that error but that's a different problem. Maybe make a new post or debug that property/pare down your code.

Comment: @objectjson I see you made a new post. Does this this one satisfy your request? Upvote and/or accept?

Comment: I do not accept what I can not upvote the questions myself, but I have questions that are important to other people, my questions are rated.anyway, I do apologize

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35593/discussion-between-ryan-and-object-json)